# Magento connect manager redirects to homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to enter Magento connect manager but it redirects me to the homepage with this strange path: *http://mysite.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fta-too.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F*

What should I do?

Comment: did you tried setting permission for downloader/index.php to 755

Comment: firstly try checking your files permission

Comment: I set permission for downloader/index.php to 644 and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded Magento and reinstalled downloader to store root directory

– Deleted my var/cache and var/sessions

– Deleted connect.cfg and cache.cfg from downloader folder

Refresh site and again connect Magento connect manager.

Answer (score 0):

firtstly if your adress is correct there will be another problem,
(adress should look like http://yoururl.something/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fyoururlencodeda%2index.php%2Fadmin%2F  this is right format of URL)

if is adress is not correct try:

lets controll base URL in System/ Configuration / Web / Secured, Unsecured and make shure there are correct addresses.
Next clear the indexes and cache in this order : 1.indexes ,2.cache

Clear the memory of your browser, or open in anonymous window.

3 in databce fing table core_config_data and check values if there is your URL in some value http://mysite.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fta-too.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F, repair to correct module Magento connect Url

Answer (score 0):

This issues occurred because you don't' have **downloader** folder in root path.
if you have **downloader** folder on root path then  delete **connect.cfg** files and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue, while clicking on magento connect manager it redirect to home page for https://www.ezizon.com/downloader/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ezizon.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F

So i download new magento fresh package and copy the Downloader folder from the root directory and paste it to my magento store root direct and save it. After that problem will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after getting a recent Magento patch (I'm now on 1.14.2.2).  I needed to make 2 coding changes to get the admin link working again and be able to resume installing extensions from the Connect Manager.  They are very simple changes but there must be a better way to change the root path from magento to magento/downloader.

To get the admin link working again, include `"index.php"` in the path returned from the `indexAction()` function in the following file:
`app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php`

More importantly, add a period ('.') as the first character to be returned from the `url()` function in the following file so the Connector Manager works again:
`downloader/Maged/Controller.php`

Answer (score 0):

I know this subject is quiet old but some people may still have this issue so I dug a bit and found how to. So For me it works like this:
https://my.website.address/downloader/index.php?A=settings
no problem with access without any permission changes etc.
Before I tried many times and it was redirecting me to 404 every time.